# unable to instantiate activity componentinfo;android manifest checked

Tags: java, android

here is logcat file:

```
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to         

  instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snotes/com.example.snotes.SAve}:                 

 java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.snotes.SAve

 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at    

 android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at      
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at     

 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at    
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at    

 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at    
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at    

 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRuntime(277):     at    

 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 07-29 20:53:41.922: E/AndroidRu`enter code herentime(277):     at       

 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MANIFEST FILE ,error is in activity SAve:

`

```
 <uses-sdk
          android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <application
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >




    <activity
             android:name=".StartingPoint"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



     <activity
         android:name=".SAve"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="shurukaro" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



  </application>

 </manifest> `
```

JAVA FILE 
the block where i start acivity,the java file that has to open is SAve.java:

```
    ` Show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     Intent i= new Intent("shurukaro");
                     startActivity(i);


        }
    });`
```

dummy  text
:
ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa 
ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa 
ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa 
ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa

ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa 
ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa 
ahoashoashfas;lifbaoisfbafbuafbajkfbkjasbfkj
asbfkabsfkjasbfkjaskjfbsakfasbfkjbasfjkbaskjfbjskabfjksabfjkasbfkjsbakfbajskfbskabfkajsb f efjb w bfweb ebf wfw efbe fbewfbewk jbfkejwb kewbfklewjbfjkwebfjkwebkjf bkbfidb fewiubfwieb webfwe bfbefbfkbfkjsd b f sb fkjds bfdsjkb fkjds bbg j rbgbgjdbgjbdgjsb ghjdsbhg bdsgbdbgjdsbjgbjdsbgsdbghrbgb  g rgbrigb rgb grbersgbireugiwgisrgsajbf bainfwefweue  u iubiugwbw iaubgi wgibgilwgrfkjbaskfksabfkjbsakjfbjskabfjkasbkfksabksabfjksa bfjsbfjsbafbsafbiufa

Comment: post the code where the error resides.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing . Are you wanting .SAve to start as the main activity everytime you start your app?

```
<intent-filter>
              <action android:name="shurukaro" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try removing what I posted and see if it works. Instead just try a normal intent. `Intent intent = new Intent(<activity name>.this, SAve.class);

startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Recheck your SAve class name again.